# not possible to route children next to components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i want to implement the login in my angular ionic application. i follow the standalone approach. when i load the components route i mean 'landingpage' , loginpage, registerpage and resetpasswordpage my code works. but when i want to load the path tabs my code fails. my tabs path points to other routes. see example. it is not possible for me to get to the other routes that are in the path tabs. i tried to implement this with the routing.navigate and routerlink but to no avail.

app.routes.ts:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LandingpagePage } from './credentialPages/landingpage/landingpage.page';
import { LoginPage } from './credentialPages/login/login.page';
import { RegisterPage } from './credentialPages/register/register.page';
import { ResetPasswordPage } from './credentialPages/reset-password/reset-password.page';


export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LandingpagePage
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginPage
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterPage
  },
  {
    path: 'reset-password',
    component: ResetPasswordPage
  },

  {
    path: 'tabs',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.routes').then((m) => m.routes),
  },
  {
    path: 'landingpage',
    component: LandingpagePage
  },

];
```

login.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Router, RouterLink, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [IonicModule, CommonModule, FormsModule,RouterModule, RouterLink]
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }


  ngOnInit() {
  }

yess(){
    this.router.navigate(['tabs/'])
  }


}
```

login.page.html:

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-back-button slot="start"></ion-back-button>
    <ion-title>Welcome to x</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
 
<div>
  
  <p>Log in to access your account</p>
</div>


<form>
  <div class="ion-padding">
    
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input></ion-input>
      <ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-input></ion-input>
      <ion-icon name="lock-closed-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>


    <div>
      <a [routerLink]="['/reset-password']"> reset pw</a>
    </div>



    <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" style="margin-bottom: 5vh; margin-right: 5vh;">
<!--       <ion-fab-button>

        <ion-button routerLink="/tabs">

        
        <ion-icon name="caret-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
      </ion-fab-button> -->


    </ion-fab>


    <button [routerLink]="['/tabs']">klick</button>
    <button (click)="yess()">klick</button>


  </div>
</form>



</ion-content>
```

'/tabs' or 'tabs' make no difference in the routerlink

tabs.routes.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';
import { Tab4Page } from '../tab4/tab4.page';
import { Tab5Page } from '../tab5/tab5.page';


export const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab2',
          loadChildren: () =>
          import('../tab2/blog-routes').then((m) => m.BlogRoutes),
      },
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../tab1/ven-routes').then((m) => m.VenRoutes),
      },
 
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../tab3/settings-routes').then((m) => m.SettingsRoutes),
      },
      {
        path: 'tab4',
          component: Tab4Page
      },
      {
        path: 'tab5',
          component: Tab5Page
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab2',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab4',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }, 
];
```

my error looks like this

```
src_app_tabs_tabs_routes_ts.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002
Error: NG04002
    at Recognizer.noMatchError (router.mjs:3662:16)
    at router.mjs:3700:28
    at catchError.js:10:39
    at OperatorSubscriber._error (OperatorSubscriber.js:23:21)
    at OperatorSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:40:18)
    at OperatorSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:64:30)
    at OperatorSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:40:18)
    at OperatorSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:64:30)
    at OperatorSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:40:18)
    at OperatorSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:64:30)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1193:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1147:17)
    at zone.js:1260:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:27437:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:173:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:581:35)
```

Comment: Where are imported your routes from the tabs.router.ts ?
If your tabs.component is standalone, you should import the tabs.routes in your tabs.component. Then, in your app.routes, lazy-load the standalone component instead.

Comment: how can i import my tabs.routes into my standalone tabs.component?

Comment: Depends if your tabs.router.ts is a module or not, but in the `import` section of your standalone component :
`RouterModule.forChild(routes)` or `TabsRouterModule`

Answer (score 0):

try removing the first / in your redirectTo in tabs.routes.ts

example:

`{ path: '', redirectTo: 'tabs/tab4', pathMatch: 'full' }`

At the moment you're pointing at your projects root folder with the first /